# i am getting 404 page not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my website.

When I click the friends button it says `404 Page Not` found.

`friends` menu code is

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $base_url.'friends/'.$session_username; ?>">Friends</a></li>
```

`friends.php` **CODE**

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';
include_once 'oauth_redirection.php';
if($_GET['username'])
{
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    include_once 'public.php';

if(empty($profile_uid))
{
    header("Location:$url404");
}
}
else
{
    header("Location:$url404");
}
?>
```

and my `.htaccess` inside

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

`block_friends_list.php` for next previous

```
<?php 
// User Friends List
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
else
{
$page=0;
}
$offset=($page-1)* $rowsPerPage;


$updatesarray=$Wall->Friends_List($profile_uid, $page, $offset, $rowsPerPage) ;

if($updatesarray)
{
 foreach($updatesarray as $data)
 {
 $friend_uid=$data['uid'];
 $friend_username=$data['username'];

$face=$Wall->User_Profilepic($friend_uid,$base_url);
 ?>
```

How do I solve this problem? Is the `.htaccess` faulty?

Comment: Since you also seem to redirect to a 404 page from your script, I think you should first find out whether the script is run at all or not. Currently, it is not clear whether the link in the first snipper generates a proper url at all? If it does, it's not clear whether the file is just not found, or the script is loaded but without proper input/parameters. Please narrow it down.

Comment: b.t.w. the htAccess said 'profile.php' and the file is called 'friends.php'.

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for reply i get this error only frieds page other page working greate.

Comment: @GolezTrol  if you can check this page [Click](http://ecoshoptr.com)
`friend`link not working but this link working greate [Click](http://ecoshoptr.com/wall-3/) `Username: srinivas`
`Password: 9lessons`

Comment: What is the URL that you see in your browser when 404 happens?

Comment: @anubhava thanks for reply mr. if you can check this page [Click](http://ecoshoptr.com) friendlink not working but this [Click](http://ecoshoptr.com/wall-3/) working greate `Username: srinivas` `Password: 9lessons`

Comment: So `http://www.ecoshoptr.com/friends/srinivas` isn't working?

Comment: @anubhava yes not working

Comment: @anubhava but if you check another link www.ecoshoptr.com/wall-3/ 
this url friend link working greate. All code is same.

Comment: What should `http://www.ecoshoptr.com/friends/srinivas` be internally rewritten to?

Comment: @anubhava I do not know how to do it with `.htaccess` .

Comment: That I am not asking. I need to know where does `/profile.php` exist? Is it in same dir as .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava profile.php is in main domain  also friends.php there

Comment: ok can you summarize what your current rewrite rule is doing?

Comment: @anubhava I have no friends folder i have only friends.php script. I want when user click firends button page URL opened like this: www.ecoshoptr.com/friends/anubhava for example. If you test my other link [www.ecoshoptr.com/wall-3/](http://www.ecoshoptr.com/wall-3/)  this friends link working. But friends link only works in the wall-3 folder.

Comment: Does `wall-3` also has a .htaccess file?

Comment: @anubhava no there is no `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^friends/([\w-]+)/?$ /friends.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^friends/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /block_friends_list.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: dear another problem will come. In a friends page has next link if i click next link it said 404 page not found error  :(

Comment: That has a link `http://www.ecoshoptr.com/friends/srinivas/2` where should this page # be used in friends.php?

Comment: This file name is `block_friends_list.php` in the same file and next previous code is : [Click] (https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t31.0-8/1900485_824731014221872_8144509280609318761_o.jpg)

Comment: You didn't get my question. If you don't answer simple question how I can answer anything. Just tell me how to pass page # 2 in `/friends/srinivas/2` to `friends.php`?

Comment: sory for my english mr. :( like `/friends/srinivas/2` to `friends.php`

Comment: You friends.php must have a GET parameter to take some action on page # being passed (see updated code though)

Comment: i add my GET parameter in my question.

Comment: i get this error :

`Fatal error: Call to a member function Friends_List() on a non-object in /home/ttmoz/public_html/block_friends_list.php on line 27` line 27 code is : `$updatesarray=$Wall->Friends_List($profile_uid, $page, $offset, $rowsPerPage) ;`